# Redirect to another website from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how to redirect from a action to an external web site like paypal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    return Redirect("http://www.paypal.com");
}
```