# ASP.NET MVC-2 Post to another website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, post

What is the best way to POST to another website (so that the users browser is redirected as well) in MVC2?  I dont want the user to be able to see the form data simply by using "view source", so I'm not keen on

```
<form action="http://other-site.com/action">
    <%= Html.TextBox("something-secret") %>
</form>
```

Is it instead possible (or advisable) to use an controller action? eg

```
public ActionResult PostTheData() 
{
    return Post("http://other-site.com/action", "something-secret");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234202/redirect-to-another-website-from-controller

Comment: I believe that return Redirect(url) does a GET, but I need a POST.

Comment: have you thought about using web services? If you have control at the other end of the request, you could just use a web service.

Comment: No control over the other side.  They require it to be a POST.

Comment: -1 This redirects to an external URL, not post data from your site to an external site, as the question indicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this persons code: [http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123193021/http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx)
to post data to the other server. And after that use Redirect(url) to redirect to the page as well.